# Setting up a guest VLAN under the same Wifi Network

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, vlan

I wonder if I can create a guest network off of my regular wifi using my DHCP to assign computers to different VLANs on the basis of their MAC addresses.

The part that I am not sure about is that one can still setup a static IP within any subnet for their device.

Comment: What network equipment are you currently using? Router, access points, etc?

Comment: I have a modem -> switch -> wifi router
                                  |
                               raspberry pi
I was thinking to add the dhcp and vlan on the pi